# Why is List Variable Changing?

Tags: python, list

I have a function and its work correct. It can calculate correct only send by one by. But I want to append every result in a list. The list variable is changing when every calculate. Why is changing appened list data ?

`

```
PLCdevice = {
    '32DI': 0,
    '16DI': 0,
    '8DI': 0
}
PLCList = []

def PLCcal(DIneed ):
    DIteklif = 12
    DItoplam = 0
    for i in range(0, 320, 8):
        DIyedek = DIteklif - DIneed
        DIoran = DIyedek / DIneed
        if DIoran > 0.26:
            break
        DIteklif = DIteklif + 8

    DIteklif = DIteklif -12
    DIteklif = DIteklif / 8

    if DIteklif / 4 >= 1 :
        x = DIteklif / 4
        PLCdevice['32DI'] = int(x)
        DIteklif = DIteklif - (int(x)*4)
    if DIteklif / 2 >= 1 :
        x = DIteklif / 2
        PLCdevice['16DI'] = int(x)
        DIteklif = DIteklif - (int(x)*2)
    if DIteklif == 1 :
        x = DIteklif / 1
        PLCdevice['8DI'] = int(x)
        DIteklif = DIteklif - (int(x)*1)
    return PLCdevice

PLCList.append(PLCcal(32))
print(PLCcal(32))
PLCList.append(PLCcal(85))
print(PLCcal(85))
PLCList.append(PLCcal(411))
print(PLCcal(411))
print(PLCList)
```

`

I try calculate result and store result in a list. But appened data is changing.

Comment: are you aware of the following 1. Dictionaries are mutable objects 2. your if statement are not mutually exclusive? So for example, `DIteklif / 4 >= 1` is `True` then `DIteklif / 2` is going to be `True` too and what you did inside the first condition will be lost.

Comment: You are modifying/returning the same global `PLCdevice` each time. You need to make a copy or new dictionary and return that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are mutable objects, and `PLCdevice` is a global variable, so every time you change it in `PLCcal` you are changing other references too which in this case are the values you are appending.

You can simply create `PLCdevice` at the beginning of `PLCcal`

```py
def PLCcal(DIneed ):
    PLCdevice = {
        '32DI': 0,
        '16DI': 0,
        '8DI': 0
    }
    ...
```